# Angular 6: How to prevent 2 subscribed variables in one Observable from cascading each other

Tags: javascript, typescript, observable, angular6

I'm facing a problem wherein there are 2 variable objects subscribed to the same Observable.

the name of the 2 variable objects are User and OriginalUser where:

User: is the object where its properties are editable.

OriginalUser: is the object where its properties should remain constant.

I construct the code like so in my component:

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private httpService: HttpClient) { }

  User: any;
  OriginalUser: any;
  userId: number;

  ngOnInit() {
    httpService.get(`https://myservername.exampledomain.com:1234/user/${userId}`)
      .subscribe((returnUser) => {
        this.User = returnUser;
        this.OriginalUser = returnUser;
      });
  }

  inputValueChange(formControlName) {
    if(this.User[formControlName] != this.OriginalUser[formControlName]) {
      console.log('not equal');
    }
    else if(this.User[formControlName] == this.OriginalUser[formControlName]) {
      console.log('is equal');
    }
  }
}
```

In the html of my component:

```
<div>
  First Name: 
  <input type="text" name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="User.firstName" (input)="inputValueChange($event.target.name)" />
</div>
```

When I test this and edit the value in the input text field. the console always displays the 'is equal' message instead of the 'not equal' message.

When I check to see what's going on to the properties of these 2 objects, I saw that the value in property of OriginalUser is cascaded by the User variable that makes it always equal value.

My problem is how can I make the value of OriginalUser's properties be constant?

Answer (score 1):

The attribute value of `OriginalUser` also changes, because `this.User` and `this.OriginalUser` are referencing the same object instance.

To make your `OriginalUser`'s attributes to be constant you need to create another instance of the User, so `this.User` and `this.OriginalUser` don't share the same object instance.

You can use [lodash clone](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#clone) function to create a new object with the same attribute values:

```
this.User = _.clone(returnUser);
```

Or you can do this manually, like following:

```
this.User = new Object();
for (key in returnUser) { // Iterates over all object attribute names
    this.User[key] = returnUser[key]; // Assigns the value of returnUser to this.User
}
```

Or

```
this.User = new Object();
let objProp = Object.keys(returnUser); // Gets all attribute names of the object as array
objProp.forEach((p: string) => { // Iterates over all got attribute names
    this.User[p] = returnUser[p]; // Assigns the value of returnUser to this.User
});
```

Comment: I have tried to manually place the property of returnUser object on loop. It works as expected. I'll also try the other ways you suggested here. btw, is loadash clone does the same as for loop do? or it's better than for loop in performance?

Comment: I tested both and the for-loop seems way faster (see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-7hfauv)), but the Lodash clone function is more powerful than the simple for-loop.